# Electron with Express or with only React and DB

Tags: reactjs, express, electron

I want to build an application with Electron. I have some questions. If I use Electron with Express, would it make my app slow? Because I read this in Electron's discussion or should I use Electron with only React. So if I use only React what should I use for the database?
By the way, I have done Electron with express but when I run the app, I also can see my application inside my web browser. Is that right or I have done something wrong?

```
const {app,browserWindow}=require('electron');

const server = require('./app');

let mainWindow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can build your renderer any frameworks as you want. Even you can build your renderer with just HTML/JS/CSS.
2. You are running express server on your main process. So it's accessible through your web browser. It's true.
3. For Database you can use any local database like sqlite3 or even you can just store your data in JSON files. Whatever you wanna be.